# Creating SQL Table with Binary and Integer values

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a table in SQL and wanted to confirm if I am creating the values properly. I need to create an integer column and a binary column. The Binary column will only have 0 for False and 1 for True. Here is my MS SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTRY(
`number` INT NOT NULL,
`bin_variable` BINARY NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ENTRY (number, bin_variable)
VALUES 
(5, 0),
(10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your value are only 0 and 1 could be you want just a boolean

```
 CREATE TABLE ENTRY(
   `number` INT NOT NULL,
   `bin_variable` boolean NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your query is correct. The table will have 2 rows with values (5,0) and (10,1)
[image: Table]

Comment: What about filtering on it in a where clause? Would it be as simple as WHERE bin_variable = 0?

Comment: @JackArmstrong Yes. `SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE bin_variable = 0;` Like this for eg.